# Search inside Json rows and sum up values

Tags: json, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I am a newbie in posgreSQL and JSON and need some help to write a query. I have a table that stores some buying history in a store. An example table is as follow:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id |                        buying_history                           |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1 | {'clothes':{'shoe':{'bob':1, 'jack':2}, 'pants':{'bob':2}}}      |
| 2 | {'clothes':{'shoe':{'mery':1, 'bob':2},'pants':{'bob':2, 'a':3}}}|
|   |   .....                                                          |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to write a query to calculates all of **bob**'s purchases and creates an output something like below:

```
------------------
| shoe  |  pants |
-----------------
| 3     |   4    |
```

The form of output is not important. Something like {'shoe':3 'pants':4} is as well. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: This looks like a case of "just because json is supported doesn't mean you should use it for everything". Why didn't you model this as relations?